# Por que o rvest quebra ao processar um arquivo vazio?

Tags: r, rvest

Ao tentar processar o conteúdo de um arquivo vazio o pacote `rvest` trava e fecha o `RStudio`. Segue pequena reprodução do problema:

```
tf <- tempfile()
file.create(tf)
html_erro <- read_html(tf)
html_erro %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
```

Por que o erro (arquivo inexistente) é tratado desta maneira? Por o `R` fecha no lugar de uma mensagem de erro aparecer?

Obrigado!

Comment: Acredito que isso seja um bug no pacote `xml2` veja o que o erro acontece quando você faz `xml2::read_html(tf)`. Acho que você deveria reportá-lo aqui: https://github.com/hadley/xml2/issues

Comment: Já reportei no `rvest`, [aqui](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/179). Até lá não custa tentar uma pergunta no SO :P

Comment: Eu só não sei se o problema está mesmo no `rvest`, como ele é apenas um wrapper do `xml2`, é bem mais provável que o problema esteja no `xml2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responderei apenas a parte: *Por que o erro acontece?*

Quando você lê um arquivo vazio com a função `read_html` do pacote `xml2` usando o código abaixo:

```
tf <- tempfile()
file.create(tf)
html_erro <- read_html(tf)
```

Você obtém uma lista com dois elementos com a classe `externalptr`. Isso pode ser observado com:

```
str(html_erro)
List of 2
 $ node:<externalptr> 
 $ doc :<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

Agora vamos observar cada um desses objetos da lista. Primeiro o `$doc`:

```
html_erro$doc
<pointer: 0x128c4d4c0>
```

Veja que ele é um ponteiro para este endereço da memória: `0x128c4d4c0`.
Agora veja o objeto `$node`:

```
html_erro$node
<pointer: 0x0>
```

Ele é um ponteiro para o endereço `0x0`. Aqui acontecerá o problema. Quando em algum momento o seu programa tentar acessar o valor deste ponteiro, ele tentará acessar um endereço de memória nulo/inexistente, causando o que é chamado de [Segmentation fault](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ou Falha de Segmentação.

No seu caso, a função `html_nodes` tentou acessar esse endereço e encontrou o problema, mas ele poderia acontecer por exemplo quando você faz `print(html_erro)`, aqui o método da função `print` para `xml_doc` tenta acessar esse ponteira e causa a falha de segmentação.

Comment: Então o problema não é com o `R`, mas com o código em `C++`?

Comment: Não necessariamente.. Mas provavelmente o R está aqui: https://github.com/hadley/xml2/blob/18c8baa9f4f508e769efb5a01302a3e14a99895e/src/xml2_doc.cpp Essa função `doc_parse_raw` deveria talvez devesse tratar essa exceção do arquivo ser vazio